# Installing Dell P713w Scanner on Debian 9

Tags: debian, scanner

I am attempting to use my Dell P713 printer/scanner on my machine. I (with some difficulty) got the printer to work, but cannot get the scanner to work.

Running, `sudo sane-find-scanner` gives the following output:

```
# sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

found USB scanner (vendor=0x413c, product=0x5236) at libusb:006:004
  # Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
  # SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.

  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.

  # You may want to run this program as root to find all devices. Once you
  # found the scanner devices, be sure to adjust access permissions as
  # necessary.
```

However, `sudo scanimage -L` outputs the following:

```
No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something different,
check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and detected by the
sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate). Please read the documentation
which came with this software (README, FAQ, manpages).
```

I edited the /etc/sane.d/lexmark.conf by adding the last two lines (I know it is not technically a Lexmark, but I actually had to use a Lexmark driver to get the printer to work):

```
# X11xx series
usb 0x043d 0x007c
# X12xx series
usb 0x043d 0x007d
# Dell A920
usb 0x413c 0x5105
# X74
usb 0x43d 0x0060
# Dell P713
usb 0x413c 0x5236
```

Because the [sane website](http://www.sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html#Z-DELL) indicates that certain Dell printers may use the xerox backend, I also attempted to add the line to the xerox configuration file without success.

Any advice would be appreciated.